# NoSuchMethod error in flume with kafka

Tags: flume, apache-kafka

kafka version is 0.7.2，flume version is 1.5.0, flume + kafka plugin: https://github.com/baniuyao/flume-kafka

error info：

2014-08-20 18:55:51,755 (conf-file-poller-0) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:149)] Unhandled error
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.math.LowPriorityOrderingImplicits.ordered()Lscala/math/Ordering;
at kafka.producer.ZKBrokerPartitionInfo$$anonfun$kafka$producer$ZKBrokerPartitionInfo$$getZKTopicPartitionInfo$1.apply(ZKBrokerPartitionInfo.scala:172)

flume configuration：

```
agent_log.sources = r1
agent_log.sinks = kafka
agent_log.channels = c1

agent_log.sources.r1.type = exec
agent_log.sources.r1.channels = c1
agent_log.sources.r1.command = tail -f /var/log/test.log

agent_log.channels.c1.type = memory
agent_log.channels.c1.capacity = 1000
agent_log.channels.c1.trasactionCapacity = 100

agent_log.sinks.kafka.type = com.vipshop.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
agent_log.sinks.kafka.channel = c1
agent_log.sinks.kafka.zk.connect = XXXX:2181

agent_log.sinks.kafka.topic = my-replicated-topic
agent_log.sinks.kafka.batchsize = 200
agent_log.sinks.kafka.producer.type = async
agent_log.sinks.kafka.serializer.class = kafka.serializer.StringEncoder
​
```

what could be the error? THX
​

Comment: This might me because I don't know about these technologies, but what exactly are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scala.math.LowPriorityOrderingImplicits.ordered()`
Perhaps you need to import the Scala standard libarary and have it in your Flume lib directory.

Comment: Thanks, the Scala jar in the Flume lib directory as fllows:        scala-compiler-2.9.2.jar  scala-library-2.8.0.jar  scala-library-2.9.2.jar

Comment: Why do you have two versions of the Scala Library? I would expect Java  to get a bit confused with that.

Comment: yeah, you are right, I delete one of them, it's seems ok! Thanks